# When button is clicked the Alert Dialog does not appear

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-alertdialog

I have an Alert Dialog that has an EditText where you input text and then add it to a ListView. Then on each item there is a Button I want to make that Button make an AlertDialog. The code below does not work.

This is my code...

```
public class DeleteRenameList extends Activity {

Button button;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(DeleteRenameList.this);
        alert.setMessage("What do you want to do?");
        alert.setPositiveButton("Rename", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alert.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            }
        });
        AlertDialog ale=alert.create();
        ale.show();

    }

 });

}}
```

Please Help.

Comment: are you have custom ListView ?? so you need to implement the onclicklistener in another place  could you post more code ??

Comment: do you have an exceptions in LogCat?

Comment: Maybe it's a permission issue. Do you have to declare 'alert' outside or static or final?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Make your custom dialog and present it:

```
//Make your class named CUstomDialogClass
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog{

    public Activity c;
    public Dialog d;
    public Button yes, no;

    public CustomDialogClass(Activity a) {
    super(a);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.c = a;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);

    }

    }

In your MainActivity, place this code in your onCreate() method:


    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourid);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final CustomDialogClass dialog = new CustomDialogClass(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setTitle("Your Title");
        dialog.show();

        final Timer time = new Timer();
        time.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, 5000);

            }
        });
```

Finally, there's the layout for custom dialog which you can modify. I just gave an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Yout Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your Message"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then you can add your listeners to it.

Hope this helps..:)

Comment: Also try setting the theme of your dialog as: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog" 

It's awesome.

Comment: Where should I put the OnCLickListener that will link it to the button? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I made the change in the code.. you can call: button.setOnClickListterner(new OnClickListener{The implementation});

Answer (score 0):

Your new onClickListener should be new View.onClickListener.
You should have something like this to start with:

```
 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v){
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This code works flawlessly on my pc, so I believe he should give it a shot.

Comment: What I meant was that there is no difference between `onClickListener` and `View.onClickListener`